# Saving RelationshipEntity not working

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I am new to Neo4J and working with Spring data repository. Following is the domain definition

```
@NodeEntity
public class Actor {
    Long id;
    private Set<Role> roles;
}

@RelationshipEntity(type="PLAYED_IN")
public class Role {
    @GraphId   private Long relationshipId;
    @Property  private String title;
    @StartNode private Actor actor;
    @EndNode   private Movie movie;
}

@NodeEntity
public class Movie {
    private Long id;
    private String title;
}
```

And have `GraphRepository` defined for each entity class 
Following code does not save the RelationshipEntity

```
Actor actor = new Actor("actorName");
actor = actorRepository.save(actor);

Movie movie = new Movie("movieTitle");
movie = movieRepository.save(movie);

Role role = new Role(actor, movie, "roleTitle");
role = roleRepository.save(role);
```

Do I have to annotate the `roles` variable in `Actor` class? 
Do I have to populate `roles` collection before saving `Actor`? If I do so then the properties on `Role` are not saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you must annotate the `roles` in the `Actor` entity.

If you're using neo4j-ogm 1.1.3 or an earlier version, make sure that when you create the new role, you add this to the collection of `roles` in the `Actor` entity.

If you're using neo4j-ogm 1.1.4-SNAPSHOT, your code should work (after you annotate the `roles`)